# MySql union query with table name

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have to write one query that will fetch data from two table. I am using `UNION` and working perfectly. But how can i recognize which row belongs to which table? 
i want data like this.

```
==================================================
          Table Name     | Person Name
==================================================
          table one      | xyz
--------------------------------------------------
          table two      | abc
--------------------------------------------------
          table one      | www
```

Comment: `SELECT 'this is table 1', * FROM table1 UNION SELECT 'this is table 2', * FROM table2`. But seriously: if you need to identify that... maybe you shouldn't be using a UNION in the first place? Just a suggestion, I don't know your reasons / requirements for having the UNION in the first place.

Comment: i have tried this in mysql. this is not working.

Comment: By all means, don't tell me _why_ it doesn't work for you, I'd like to spend my time guessing, as I have way to much free time on my hands ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add an extra column to your query like

```
select col1,col2,...,coln,'Table1' as Tablename from table1
Union
select col1,col2,...,coln,'Table2' as Tablename from table2
```